# Where does Web2py save project files OS X?

Tags: python, macos, web2py

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out where web2py stores the project files by default in OS X. It is not located in the same directoy as the web2py.app .

I can launch the web interface and see project in the admin view but want to edit the files from sublime text as opposed to the admin web interface.

I've looked through the web2py book and google user book with no luck. Any suggestions, this seems like it should be fairly obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Mac binary, I think the applications are in /web2py/web2py.app/Contents/Resources/applications/.

Note, you can also run the source version of web2py, in which case, the applications will be in /web2py/applications/.

Comment: THanks Anthony! Gah, you think they could have included this info in the documentation. I mean really!

Comment: It is 2016 and it is still the case as I just started using web2py this month. Note, if you are on a Mac, web2py.app is actually a directory (maybe it is technically a package, I'm not sure), but, to get into it's contents, you must either right click, or if you are using a terminal window you can 'cd' straight into it. If you try to open it like a regular folder, Finder will launch the web2py app. Just in case others like me see this post, and then struggle to get into the contents for lack of knowledge about what an ".app" file is.

Comment: @Anthony, Why's there a difference?

Comment: @Pacerier, the binary requires creation of a Mac application bundle, which has a particular directory structure (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW19)).